# Rails save into 2 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash, amazon-s3

I have array of hashes and want to iterate through it and save into db

```
products = [
    {
        "currencyId"=>"UAH",
        "categoryId"=>"9395236",
        "picture"=> [
            "http://images.ua.prom.st/427654530_w640_h640_cid2043281_pid296482296-1fdb5252.jpg",
            "http://images.ua.prom.st/427654531_w640_h640_cid2043281_pid296482296-d1bd8ab8.jpg"
        ],
        "pickup"=>"true",
        "delivery"=>"true",
        "name"=>"VOX - Vox Ac15Vr ",
        "vendor"=>"VOX",
        "vendorCode"=>"D000951"},
    {
        other similar hash
    },
    {
        other similar hash
    }   
]
```

so i want to do something like:

```
products.each do |product|
    Product.create(name:product['name']...)

    # and than save images to AWS , but i even don't imagine how to do it. Because i don't have saved product.
end
```

I have the class `Product` with `has_many :photos` and class `Photo` with `belongs_to :product`

Is it possible?

Comment: Please do some reading about rails associations, gems like carrierwave, fog etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to do what you like. Using it you would have something like:

Your Photo would be like:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file   :content, 
                        styles: { 
                            medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" 
                        }
    validates_attachment_content_type :content, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

    belongs_to :product
end
```

Your Product would be like:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :photos, autosave: true
end
```

So with that you could save them at your loop:

```
products.each do |product|
    p = Product.new(name: product['name']...)
    p.photos << Photo.new(content: _image_file)
    p.photos << Photo.new(content: _another_image_file)
    p.save
end
```

And Paperclip have support to S3, so you just have to configure how you want it to work.

Comment: tnx,thats what i need

Answer (score 3):

You can use carrierwave to upload file but if you want o save string, then you can do it manually.

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave